# Is $D_{2^{n+1}}/Z_2\cong D_{2^n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups

I run into a problem when I try to solve a question, show $D_{2^{n+1}}/Z(D_{2^{n+1}})\cong D_{2^n}$.
Note: $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order 2n.
I have shown $D_{2^{n+1}}/Z(D_{2^{n+1}})\cong D_{2^{n+1}}/Z_2$.
But I am not sure how to show $D_{2^{n+1}}/Z_2\cong D_{2^n}$

Thank you.

Comment: “$D_{2^{n+1}}/Z_2$“ does not *quite* make sense, since $Z_2$, the integers modulo $2$, are not a literal subgroup of $D_{2^{n+1}}$. It is isomorphic to a *particular* subgroup (in fact, to many, but just to one normal one). You **really** need to know who $Z(D_{2^{n+1}})$ is as a specific subgroup, and use that.

Comment: As to how to prove it, it depends on exactly how you “know” the dihedral groups. By a presentation? As specific subgroups of symmetric/permutation groups given by generators? As “group of symmetries” of specific objects?

Comment: thank you for the comments, i used <$r^{2^n}$>, and it worked out.

Comment: The isomorphism holds more generally for $D_m$, and $D_{2m}/Z$. In your case, $m=2^n$.